# Adding quotations to stringified JSON object values

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

My stringified object data doesn't include quotation marks around object values, which errors when attempting `JSON.parse()`:

```
'{ "affiliation": CORPORATE, "userId": 75c35d1c-5d12-4485-8fa8-b2f1551a3e6e }'
```

I need the string to be:

```
'{ "affiliation": "CORPORATE", "userId": "75c35d1c-5d12-4485-8fa8-b2f1551a3e6e" }'
```

I'm using this regex to add quotes to the object keys:

```
var newStr = str.replace(/(['"])?([a-z0-9A-Z_]+)(['"])?:/g, '"$2": ');
```

For instance: 
    `'{ affiliation: CORPORATE }'` to `'{ "affiliation": CORPORATE }'`

There are only string values in my data, so I don't need to check value types. How can I alter my regex expression to add quotations to object values as well?

Comment: @ACD my regex currently adds quotes to the object key, but doesn't add quotes to the object value

Comment: Is it really impossible to fix the other side that generates it incorrectly?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, this data is coming from a neo4j dump converted to CVS but the original source doesn't wrap quotes

Comment: is there a guarantee that special values like spaces, `,` `:` or `"` will not be present in the stringified object? If not, how would you add quotes to `{ a key: a value, maybe key: value: 2}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/[ ](?=\b)|\b(?=,|[ ])/g
```

It starts matching a Space and use a look ahead for a `Word boundary`. It then uses an alternation for a `Word boundary` followed by a `comma` or a `Space`.

It uses the `'global'` flag to match all.

Then you replace the matches with a `double quote`.